# how to click by attribute in selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

HTML structure:

```
<g class="bars">
    <rect class="bar selected" x="81" y="79" width="66" height="126">
    <rect class="bar selected" x="169" y="79" width="66" height="126">
    <rect class="bar selected" x="257" y="60" width="66" height="145">
</g>
```

I need to click in bar selected with attribute x=81.
How to do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Find the element *by xpath*. Example (using `python` bindings):

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//g[@class="bars"]/rect[@x="81"]')
element.click()
```

There are certainly multiple ways to find that element. For instance, you can get the first `rect` out of the `g` tag:

```
//g[@class="bars"]/rect[1]
```

Or, you can additionally check the `class` attribute:

```
//g[@class="bars"]/rect[@class="bar selected"][1]
```

Or, you can combine the options I've mentioned and make your own xpath. It really depends on the uniqueness of the element and it's attributes across the page. Difficult to say without seeing the complete HTML source of the page.